# Unix-compatible Perl command

Tags: shell, perl, unix, posix

The piece of code that I am doing now is for converting a date/timestamp to milliseconds.

The date parameters don't work on my Unix box like -d i get an error message
(date: illegal option -- d
Usage: date [-u] [+Field Descriptors]).

So the requirement is as below i have an input date in below format and i want to convert it to milliseconds. Example

```
Input Date = 2017-09-19 19:36:12.763
Output (in milliseconds) = 1567299281726 (something similar)
```

Hope this makes sense now?

Comment: I'm sorry, what? Please [edit] your question and tell us again what you need help with. There is no question in your question. If you are having trouble with English, use Google Translate and write normally in your native language. That's probably easier to understand for us.

Comment: Are you saying that you want a way to convert a date-time string to milliseconds without using Perl?

Comment: This is my Input Date = 2017-09-19 19:36:12.763
And i expect the output in this format Output(in milliseconds) = 1567299281726 (something similar).

Comment: Borodin yes thats right !!

Comment: And are you also saying that: (1) `date` paramenters don't work on your system (2) you don't want to use Perl ... ?  How do you get that "Input Date"?  (Is this some shell?)  What system are you on?

Answer (score 1):

Similar to your perl command, the GNU date command does not handle milliseconds. You could do this (in bash or ksh)

```
input_date="2017-09-19 19:36:12.763"
IFS=. read -r datetime milliseconds <<<"$input_date"
date -d "$datetime" "+%s$milliseconds"
```

```
1505864172763
```

Then, to go the other way:

```
timestamp=1505864172763
milliseconds=$(( timestamp % 1000 ))
date -d "@$((timestamp / 1000))" "+%F %T.$milliseconds"
```

```
2017-09-19 19:36:12.763
```